# How to parse JSON passed on the command line

Tags: python, json

I am trying to pass JSON parameters through command line in Python:

```
automation.py {"cmd":"sel_media","value":"5X7_photo_paper.p}
```

how can I extract the values `sel_media` and `5X7_photo_paper.p`?

I used the following code, but it is not working:

```
cmdargs = str(sys.argv[1])
print cmdargs
```

Comment: Your JSON value is not properly formatted (missing quote)

Answer (score 4):

Provided you pass actual valid JSON to the command line and quote it correctly, you can parse the value with the [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).

You need to quote the value properly, otherwise your shell or console will interpret the value instead:

```
automation.py '{"cmd":"sel_media","value":"5X7_photo_paper.p"}'
```

should be enough for a bash shell.

In Python, decode with [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads):

```
import sys
import json

cmdargs = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
print cmdargs['cmd'], cmdargs['value']
```

Demo:

```sh
$ cat demo.py 
import sys
import json

cmdargs = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
print cmdargs['cmd'], cmdargs['value']

$ bin/python demo.py '{"cmd":"sel_media","value":"5X7_photo_paper.p"}'
sel_media 5X7_photo_paper.p
```

Answer (score 1):

The above is generally correct, but I ran into issues with it when running on my own python script

```
python myscript.py '{"a":"1"}'
```

does not work directly in my terminal

so I did

```
python myscript.py '{\"a\":\"1\"}'
```